# Copy rows into same table except primary key and auto increment columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Is it possible to copy some rows in a table excluding the primary key and auto increment columns?

I found only one solution:

1. create a temp table
2. drop primary column

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Copy to where, do you want to insert into same table?

Comment: Yes i want to insert in exactly same table

Comment: Note sure what the issue is?, if its an auto incrementing column then dont specify it (it will be populated for you). If copying into a new table use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTABLE ON`, then put if off when done

Comment: @Andrew Is it safe if another row will be inserted at the same time?

Comment: It should be yes, it will just get a new id but have all the same data, it does raise questions why you want the same data row though, lol

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM TableName
WHERE <<your logic to filter rows>>
```

Update

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA Varchar(100) = 'dbo',
        @TABLE_Name Varchar(100) = 'MyTable',
        @TableColumns Varchar(1000),
        @RequiredColumns Varchar(1000),
        @SQLStatement VARCHAR(4000)

SET @TableColumns = ''

SELECT 
    @TableColumns = @TableColumns + Name + ' , ' 
FROM syscolumns 
WHERE id = object_id(@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_Name) 
  AND Name NOT IN (SELECT col.name  
                   FROM sys.tables tab
                   INNER JOIN sys.indexes pk ON tab.object_id = pk.object_id 
                                             AND pk.is_primary_key = 1
                   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = pk.object_id 
                                                   AND ic.index_id = pk.index_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON pk.object_id = col.object_id 
                                              AND col.column_id = ic.column_id
                   WHERE tab.object_id = object_id(@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_Name))

SET @RequiredColumns = Substring(@TableColumns,1,len(@TableColumns)-1) 

SELECT @SQLStatement = 'INSERT INTO MyTable (' + @RequiredColumns + ') SELECT ' + Substring(@TableColumns,1,len(@TableColumns)-1) + ' FROM '+@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_Name

-- you can add the required where condition to filter rows

EXEC(@SQLStatement)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem with the example above, is that, if i will add one cell in table, i need to implement it again.

Comment: @GiorgosPapadopoulos your question was not clear. update the answer with dynamic sql so it will work if you add new columns/removed any existing columns in future

Comment: @GiorgosPapadopoulos - If you change the columns of a table, then you ***should*** be changing the code.  If you're changing the columns of a table regularly, you've probably got a broken design and should look at ways of avoiding adding columns frequently.